# Parsing Text file having repeated value key pair using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, text-files

I have a text file that has the pattern as below..I would like to parse the values for each " An instance of Alert" and assign the values to the variables number,type,source etc..... What is the best option to accomplish this

```
An instance of Alert
      number=2
      type=Server
      source=ARRAY.R800.56794
      severity=4
      component=DKC Environment
      description=Moderate error reported for DKC Environment.
      actionToTake=Contact your service representative.
      data=The component is not fully functional.
      timeOfAlert=2018/05/26 04:52:17
    An instance of Alert
      number=1
      type=Server
      source=ARRAY.R800.57457
      severity=4
      component=DKC Environment
      description=Moderate error reported for DKC Environment.
      actionToTake=Contact your service representative.
      data=The component is not fully functional.
      timeOfAlert=2018/05/26 04:07:42

def GetAlerts(serialNumber,arrayType):
    print("Collecting Alert Data")
    remove(HiCommandCLI_XML_Path+"GetAlerts.txt")
    sourcefilter ="ARRAY."+arrayType+"."+serialNumber
    cmd = "/san02/hds/OAC/HiCommandCLI GetAlerts sourcefilter=%s -o %s/GetAlerts.txt" % (sourcefilter,HiCommandCLI_XML_Path)
    os.system(cmd)

# Parse the TEST to the text file as "Component" "Identifier" "Status"    
#"Result" format
    xmlfile = HiCommandCLI_XML_Path+'/GetAlerts.txt'
    with open (xmlfile, "r") as alertfile:
        s=alertfile.readlines()
    for block in s.split("An instance of Alert"):
        for line in block.strip().splitlines(): 
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                print(line.split("="))
        print("------")
```

Expect output (in variables as I dont want to print but process the variables)
I would be doing some calculations using the other variables from each block..so basically, I need to consider each block as an object and extract values number,type,source etc... from each block

```
    number=2 type=server source=ARRAY.R800.56794
    number=1 type=server source=ARRAY.R800.57457
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

```
s = """An instance of Alert
      number=2
      type=Server
      source=ARRAY.R800.56794
      severity=4
      component=DKC Environment
      description=Moderate error reported for DKC Environment.
      actionToTake=Contact your service representative.
      data=The component is not fully functional.
      timeOfAlert=2018/05/26 04:52:17
An instance of Alert
      number=1
      type=Server
      source=ARRAY.R800.57457
      severity=4
      component=DKC Environment
      description=Moderate error reported for DKC Environment.
      actionToTake=Contact your service representative.
      data=The component is not fully functional.
      timeOfAlert=2018/05/26 04:07:42"""

for block in s.split("An instance of Alert"):    #use str.split on "An instance of Alert"
    for line in block.strip().splitlines():      #Iterate each line in block
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            print(line.split("="))                #Get Value
     print("------")
```

**Output:**

```
------
['number', '2']
['type', 'Server']
['source', 'ARRAY.R800.56794']
['severity', '4']
['component', 'DKC Environment']
['description', 'Moderate error reported for DKC Environment.']
['actionToTake', 'Contact your service representative.']
['data', 'The component is not fully functional.']
['timeOfAlert', '2018/05/26 04:52:17']
------
['number', '1']
['type', 'Server']
['source', 'ARRAY.R800.57457']
['severity', '4']
['component', 'DKC Environment']
['description', 'Moderate error reported for DKC Environment.']
['actionToTake', 'Contact your service representative.']
['data', 'The component is not fully functional.']
['timeOfAlert', '2018/05/26 04:07:42']
------
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GetStorageArray.py", line 420, in <module>
    getArrayName(sys.argv[1])
  File "./GetStorageArray.py", line 61, in getArrayName
    GetAlerts(serialNumber,arrayType)
  File "./GetStorageArray.py", line 393, in GetAlerts
    for block in s.split("An instance of Alert"):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Appreciate it. ! How do I get those values in to variable, to print in one row like, number+type+source+.....so on..... I need to process each block as one entity

Comment: Can you post expected output?